# FORTRAN 90 How to find out the number of files on a folder

Tags: file, fortran, directory, fortran90

quick doubt, I need to read all the files from a folder, but I don't know how many files are there.

I know how to open them all, just don't know when to stop, i.e. when all the files are read.

Comment: if you want a program to operate on a bunch of files, the usual  approach is to pass the files as arguments on the command line when you run the program.  Then of course you question becomes how to process command line arguments..

Answer (score 4):

If you have a certain rule to generate the file names (e.g. mydata001.dat, mydata002.dat, etc.), then you can every time you generate a file name, you can check with the `inquire` statement, whether the file exists. The first time it does not exist, you can stop. The program below demonstrates that:

```
program proba
  implicit none

  character(len=20) :: buffer
  logical :: exist
  integer :: ind

  ind = 1
  fileloop: do
    write(buffer,"(A,I3.3,A)") "mydata", ind, ".dat"
    inquire(file=buffer, exist=exist)
    if (.not. exist) then
      write(*,*) "File '", trim(buffer), "' not found, exiting loop"
      exit
    end if
    write(*,*) "File: '", trim(buffer), "' found."
    ind = ind + 1
  end do fileloop

end program proba
```

Alternatively, if the file names can not be generated according a rule, you may use some libraries which enable to get a list of files in a directory. One possibility could be my [modFileSys](https://bitbucket.org/aradi/modfilesys/) library, where you could do it for arbitrary directory content the following way:

```
program test_ls
  use filesys_module

  type(dirdesc) :: dir
  character(:), allocatable :: path

  call opendir("./", dir)
  path = dir%next_filename()
  do while (len(path) > 0)
    write(*, "(A)") path
    path = dir%next_filename()
  end do

end program test_ls
```

Comment: The second scenario is where I'm at. I'll try using your library, thank you.

Meanwhile I was looking for another solution, I was thinking about using the system(command) to get the list of files using linux command, but was having trouble figuring out what was the right syntax for the compiler i have.

Comment: That would be a non-standard solution, as it is a language extension provided by your compiler. Fortran 2008 has the `execute_command_line` routine, which maybe your compiler already implements. However, even this won't provide you the list of the files directly...

Comment: neither the typical call system() not execute_command_line gives you back the output, so you need to do something ugly like direct a directory list to a scratch file and then open and read the file.

Comment: You are correct george, that was the solution I've chosen.

Let me explain better, the program have to read some files in order to run, these files are provided by the user, neither, it's names or quantity is known by the program.

How is that solution of passing the files as parameters? Is it a good solution if you have say 1000 files?